# How to insert an ID into another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm practising triggers on Oracle and I'm having troubles with this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MODIFICACIONES_SALARIOS AFTER
    UPDATE OF salario ON empleados_pac
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_username VARCHAR(10);
    v_hora VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT user INTO v_username FROM dual;
    SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:ss') INTO v_hora FROM dual;
    
    INSERT INTO audita_salarios (id_emp, salario_antiguo, salario_nuevo, fecha, hora, username) VALUES (id_empleado, :old.salario, :new.salario, sysdate, v_hora, v_username);
END;
```

I'm doing an historic table where when the salary of the employeer changes the trigger inserts in the historic his ID, the old salary, the new one, the date and the user who changed the salary.
All works perfectly except for the ID insert. Oracle says that the column is not allowed.

I think the problem is because I want to insert an unique ID into a new column where the ID is going to be repeated if the salary changes two or more times. How could I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using the `hora` column? The data is already in the `fecha` column (assuming that it has the `DATE` data type).

Comment: The exercise want this table:  id_emp NUMBER(2),
    salario_antiguo NUMBER(10,2),
    salario_nuevo NUMBER(10,2),
    fecha DATE,
    hora VARCHAR2(10),
    username VARCHAR2(10)

Comment: Maybe so, but my point is that the `hora` column is pointless as `fecha` is already storing the date and time.

Comment: Well maybe, but they ask for it and it works. My problem is with the ids...

Comment: You should **NEVER** store date/time values as string. You don't need any `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM dual` - Use simply  `INSERT INTO audita_salarios (...) VALUES (..., SYSDATE, USER);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the problem is because I want to insert an unique ID into a new column where the ID is going to be repeated if the salary changes two or more times. How could I fix this?

Do not have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `audita_salarios.id_emp`; instead have a composite `UNIQUE` constraint on `id_emp` and `fecha` (if you need a `UNIQUE` constraint at all).

Also:

- use a virtual column for `HORA` (or remove that column as it is just duplicating the time component of `FECHA`);
- use `:NEW.id_empleado` rather than `id_empleado` in the trigger.

```sql
CREATE TABLE empleados_pac (
  id_empleado NUMBER(2),
  salario     NUMBER(10,2)
);

CREATE TABLE audita_salarios (
  id_emp          NUMBER(2),
  salario_antiguo NUMBER(10,2),
  salario_nuevo   NUMBER(10,2),
  fecha           DATE, 
  hora            VARCHAR2(8)
                  GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CAST( TO_CHAR( fecha, 'HH24:MI:SS' ) AS VARCHAR2(8) ) ),
  username        VARCHAR2(60),
  CONSTRAINT      audita_salarios__pk PRIMARY KEY ( id_emp, fecha )
);

CREATE TRIGGER MODIFICACIONES_SALARIOS
  AFTER UPDATE OF salario ON empleados_pac
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO audita_salarios (
      id_emp, salario_antiguo, salario_nuevo, fecha, username
    ) VALUES (
      :new.id_empleado, :old.salario, :new.salario, sysdate, USER
    );
END;
/

INSERT INTO empleados_pac ( id_empleado, salario ) VALUES ( 1, 10 );

UPDATE empleados_pac
SET    salario = 20
WHERE  id_empleado = 1;

BEGIN
  DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP(1);
END;
/

UPDATE empleados_pac
SET    salario = 30
WHERE  id_empleado = 1;

-- You do not actually need to constraint on the audit table unless you
-- want to enforce that salary updates must be on different times.

ALTER TABLE audita_salarios DROP CONSTRAINT audita_salarios__pk;

UPDATE empleados_pac
SET    salario = 40
WHERE  id_empleado = 1;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM audita_salarios;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID_EMP | SALARIO_ANTIGUO | SALARIO_NUEVO | FECHA               | HORA     | USERNAME                   
> -----: | --------------: | ------------: | :------------------ | :------- | :--------------------------
>      1 |              10 |            20 | 2021-04-01 13:02:42 | 13:02:42 | FIDDLE_XRWUFWRAYDJNIGNCOQFP
>      1 |              20 |            30 | 2021-04-01 13:02:43 | 13:02:43 | FIDDLE_XRWUFWRAYDJNIGNCOQFP
>      1 |              30 |            40 | 2021-04-01 13:02:43 | 13:02:43 | FIDDLE_XRWUFWRAYDJNIGNCOQFP
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6b0f89d374893b080b50c87e0962c0ca)*

Comment: I just fixed my problem by doing id_empleado -> :old.id_empleado. Thank you anyway